# Select first item of pivot column

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a code to switch pivot fields from absolute values to an index.

```
Private Sub Index_Change()
Dim p As PivotTable
Dim f As PivotField




Set p = Sheets("1").PivotTables("2")

With p.PivotFields("Sum of 1")
        .Calculation = xlPercentOf
        .BaseItem = ""
        .NumberFormat = "0,00%"
    End With



    End Sub
```

I am looking for a way to select the first cell of the pivot column as the `.BaseItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer by simply recording a macro which showed me the appropriate code:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pfI As PivotField, pfB As PivotField

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1") 'adjust to your table
Set pfI = pt.PivotFields("myIndexColumn") 'adjust to your table
Set pfB = pt.PivotFields("myBaseField") 'adjust to your table

With pfI

    .Calculation = xlPercentOf
    .BaseField = pfB.Name
    .BaseItem = pfB.PivotItems(1).Name
    .NumberFormat = "0.00%"

End With
```

For clarity sake, the macro recorder did not show me the code above exactly as written, but I adjusted it to make it more dynamic for coding. The code the recorder showed is below (I left in my pivot table field names):

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Loan Amounts")
    .Calculation = xlPercentOf
    .BaseField = "Loan Type"
    .BaseItem = "C&I"
    .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
End With
```